# Fragment shader in WebGL - Modeling a light

Tags: glsl, webgl

I've written a fragment shader mainly trying to mimic other examples. Almost every lines is clear, but I would like to understand if this could be considered a per fragment lighting or just a vertex lighting. And generally, how can I improve this?

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D sampler; /*Values passed from application via uniform1i*/
varying vec2 f_uv; //Texture uv coordinates passed from application
const vec3 source_ambient_color = vec3(0.8,0.8,0.8);/*Source light*/
const vec3 source_diffuse_color = vec3(0.5,0.5,0.5);
const vec3 source_specular_color = vec3(1.,1.,1.);
const vec3 source_direction = vec3(0.,0.,1.);/*source position (is this a point light?)*/
const vec3 material_ambient_color = vec3 (0.8,0.8,0.8);/*Material properties*/
const vec3 material_diffuse_color = vec3 (0.5,0.5,0.5);
const vec3 material_specular_color = vec3 (1.,1.,1.);
const float material_glossiness = 10.;/*Glossiness*/
varying vec3 v_normal;/*Values of vertices normals, coming from application*/
varying vec3 vView;/*Camera View*/

void main()  {
             vec3 color = vec3(texture2D(sampler,f_uv)); /*assigns to the variable color the pixel of the texure*/
             vec3 I_ambient = source_ambient_color*material_ambient_color;/*calculate by multiply the source ambient by the material ambient (I think they'd better share the same value, for realistic result)*/
             vec3 I_diffuse = source_diffuse_color*material_diffuse_color*max(0.,dot(v_normal, source_direction));/*calculate the scalar product of the angle between viewing direction and light position to produce a correct diffuse*/
             vec3 V = normalize(vView); /*normalize viewing vector to calculate angle later*/ 
             vec3 R = reflect(source_direction,v_normal);/*I believe this returns the angle between viewing direction and light position and computes the reflection*/
             vec3 I_specular = source_specular_color*material_specular_color*pow(max(dot(R,V),0.), material_glossiness); /*scalar product of viewing and reflect (I believe to compute the intensity of the specular effect*/
             vec3 I = I_ambient+I_diffuse+I_specular;/*add the previous calculation togheter to produce a light model*/
             gl_FragColor = vec4(I*color,1);/*multiply the texture color by the lighting model to simulate the lighting*/
             }
```

Comment: You're computing lighting in the fragment shader so it's per-fragment (or per-pixel) lighting. If you were to compute lighting in the vertex shader and interpolate the resulting colour then it'd be per-vertex. To improve it I'd fix the `*/Source light/*` comment. What does it not do that you'd like it to do?

Comment: Just a comment error, I've fixed it in the edit. I just wanna know if there are other light models to apply. And how to model them, given that my example is a valid starting point.

Comment: I would then say this question is too broad for SO. You've written a per-pixel phong shader. Yes there are many many lighting models. The realm of material modelling is huge and very interesting, so you might like to read more about it. Phong is pretty common, I'd stick with it unless you see something else you need.

Comment: I was in your position not so long ago so heres a couple suggestions on where to go from there: 1) add gamma correction; 2) add attenuation; 3) add limitations to where the light lit so you have spotlight 4) write javascript wrapper/managers to deal with light/material uniforms; 5) implement multiple lights 6) add shadows; Oh and just to add per pixel Phong shading is already pretty nice for most applications, the next biggest bang for buck improvement would be normal maps imo.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. If you have links about that, throw them in. Thanks WacławJasper.